# How can I determine whether a JDBC driver is Type 4?

Tags: java, jdbc

We have an application that runs on Java 1.6 and has the ability to talk to RDBMS systems via custom plugins. We don't care what type of database a customer has, but we did decide to require a Type 4 driver, for a variety of reasons.

I want to programmatically decide whether a driver is Type 4 so that I can reject it right away rather than spend time debugging problems later only to find out that the driver is not Type 4. Since I don't know what the vendor is, I can't just look at the version number. I've looked at Driver.jdbcCompliant() but this is not a necessary condition for the driver being Type 4. I've also looked at creating a Connection and then doing reflection on it to see if it implements certain methods like isValid(), but again I realized this does not necessarily guarantee the driver is Type 4. Any suggestions?

Comment: i doesn't think there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Seems like I was talking about something different anyway!

Get the `DatabaseMetaData` via `Connection.getMetaData()` and check that [getJDBCMajorVersion()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getJDBCMajorVersion%28%29) >= 4. You may want to catch `NoSuchMethodException` when calling that method, since only a JDBC 3.0+ driver will have it.

**Edit:** Hmm, this seems like it should be right but... Oracle doesn't seem to implement it correctly, since I get 11.2 for the JDBC version. That's the same thing I get for the driver version. Thanks Oracle!

If you can't count on the methods specifically designed for this, it seems to me that your only option is to call methods like `createClob()` on `Connection` and catch `NoSuchMethodException`. That or add special handling for specific vendors.

Comment: the major/minor versions represent the jdbc version being supported and not the driver types. for e.g. there is a type 4 driver in jdbc 3 and calling getJDBCMajorVersion() in jdbc 3 doesnt return 4

Comment: @Pangea: I feel like the question is about JDBC versions rather than types, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I actually do care about the Type and not so much the JDBC version. Like Pangea mentioned, you can have a Type 4 driver which implements the JDBC 3.0 spec and not the 4.0 spec, and vice versa. What we care about are the semantics (i.e. native-protocol) that comes with Type 4 drivers. Although since we require Java 1.6 it is important that the driver is compatible with Java 1.6 as well (I know some drivers are compiled with a pre-JDK6 and are not compatible with JDK6.. I'm not sure how to discover this either). But most important in the driver Type.

Comment: @JT-3: I got the impression you were talking about version from the part where you said one option might be to check if the `Connection` has the `isValid` method, which would only be related to the version I would think.